# how to get sum of the numbers in for loop laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a loop where each step I get the price of the day. Now I want to get the sum of all days and show them to the user. Here is my attempt below:

```php
for ($f = 0; $f < count($room_ids); $f++) {
    $data = Price::whereIn('id',$room_ids)
        ->whereDate('from_date', '<', $from_date)
        ->whereDate('to_date', '>   ', $to_date)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
        ->take(1)
        ->get();
//    $sum_price += array_sum($data[$f]->sales_price)
//or this one 
//    $sum_price += $data[$f];
    $data_array[] = $data[$f]->sales_price.'======'.$dates[$i].'==============' ;
}
```

but each time I get the price for 1 day and don't get the sum of all days. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please add sample table data to your question along with the expected result.  I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: $data which means price model has a price property that i want to get the sum of it .

Comment: Why do you have the `for` loop?. Query inside loop will always be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$sum_price[] = $data[$f]->sales_price;
// here use this and outside of your loop do an array sum
$sum = array_sum($sum_price);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sum function in Laravel Eloquent. Please check [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sum-of-column) for detail.

```
$sum_price = 0;
$data = Price::
      whereIn('id',$room_ids)
      ->whereDate('from_date', '<', $from_date)
      ->whereDate('to_date', '>   ', $to_date)
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
       ->sum('price');
$sum_price = $data[0];
echo $sum_price; // This will give you total price.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sum_price = 0;
$data = Price::
      where`enter code here`In('id',$room_ids)
      ->whereDate('from_date', '<', $from_date)
      ->whereDate('to_date', '>   ', $to_date)
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
       ->sum('price');
$sum_price = $data[0];
echo $sum_price;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very confusing and doesn't make much sense.

For example why you are using a `for` loop? your query will always return the same result, so whats the point of the loop?

what is `$i`?

Since your query always returns one result `->take(1)` so only `$data[0]` will have a value, what is `$data[$f]` supposed to return for example `$data[1]`, `$data[2]` etc.

You could just sum the prices with the query builder

```
$sum = Price::whereIn('id', $room_ids)
    ->whereDate('from_date', '<', $from_date)
    ->whereDate('to_date', '>', $to_date)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->sum('sales_price');
```